# jQuery errorPlacement submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validate, and have my errors written to a `div`, which is working fine. What I want to do is have the `div` hidden, and when the validation returns any errors, the `div` shows at the top of the form. I'm not sure of the correct trigger to show the `div`.

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
    <div id="valwrapper" class="hide">
    Validation Errors<br/><br/>
        <div id="valerrors"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $('#valerrors').append(error);
},

submitHandler: function(){
    $("#valwrapper").slideDown("fast");
},
errorContainer: "#valerors",
//errorLabelContainer: "#valerrors",
//wrapper: "span", debug: true,
onfocusout: false,
onkeyup: false,
onclick: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete answer.  Might as well post it, since I've been working on it.

You will not need `errorPlacement:` since the plugin automatically handles this for you when you use `errorLabelContainer:`

http://jsfiddle.net/SaLNp/4/

```
$('form').validate({
    invalidHandler: function() {
        $("#valwrapper").slideDown("fast");
    },
    errorContainer: "#valwrapper",
    errorLabelContainer: "#valerrors",
    wrapper: "span",
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false
});​
```

Documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0):

Folks, just stupidity on my part. The code should have "invalidHandler" not "submitHandler".

Comment: See my answer which makes a few minor adjustments.  For example, you don't need to specify `errorPlacement:` at all since the plugin automatically uses your `errorLabelContainer:` option.